# I am trying to take count of no of rows fetched from a dataframe using spark sql. But I am getting the below error

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to take count of no of rows fetched from a dataframe using spark sql. But I am getting the below error. Can some one help me with resolving this issue?

**My sql query** 
collisions is my temperoray table name and i am trying to show the results.

```
outputDataframe = spark.sql("select count(*) from collisions where     YEAR(date) = 2016")
outputDataframe.show()
```

**Error :**

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o395.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 13, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PARKING LOT)."

Comment: Seems like log is not correct/complete as "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PARKING LOT" does not represent anything. Try giving schema name in front of table if it is not in default schema.

Comment: Its my mistake. The dataset I have taken is not proper. issue is solved after formatting the dataset